# Onclick javascript button click show available records of custom object

Tags: javascript, custom-button, detail-page, onclick

I have a requirement to have a custom button on Account detail page. A click on that should show all available records for logged in User of a custom object Approved_Documents_vod__c. This object has no direct relation with Account. Please let me know if that is possible without any visualforce page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please create a Custom button on the Object where you want to show all records and below is the Code for the custom button:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/32.0/connection.js")} 

// Quering the database and Example Query and you can modify it as per your requirement

var result = sforce.connection.query("Select ID From Opportunity"); 

// Getting all records from the query to the array 
var records = result.getArray("records"); 

alert(records);
```

Note: You don't have to write any visualforce page and there is no relation between the objects.